# Firebase Emulators: Deploy target with demo-project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm working in a Firebase Project with an Angular App.

I'm setup the emulators as I usually do, but this time I cannot start them.

The command I'm using is:

`"start": "firebase emulators:exec --project demo-project --ui 'ng serve'",`

And this is what happens:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/real-project-name/frontend (1-add-angular-fire) $ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ firebase emulators:exec --project demo-project --ui 'ng serve'
⚠  emulators: You are not currently authenticated so some features may not work correctly. Please run firebase login to authenticate the CLI.
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, eventarc
i  emulators: Detected demo project ID "demo-project", emulated services will use a demo configuration and attempts to access non-emulated services for this project will fail.
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: Deploy target real-project-name not configured for project demo-project. Configure with:

  firebase target:apply hosting real-project-name <resources...>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Do you know why this is happening? Can you help me fix this?

Comment: What's in your firebase.json file? Are you using demo-project in your firebase config that you use to `initializeApp`?

Comment: This is my firebase json file: https://gist.github.com/ezequieltejada/8b1d235fa03840caae90e8ad26a2eca5#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: In the same link I've added the firebase config that I use to work with the emulators.